# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cvzone' in visual studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, cvzone

I was trying to import cvzone and cv2 library in vs code but it gives this error no matter what I do.

Tried to install this through cmd with pip and vs code (again, with pip) but nothing changes
python version 3.11.2
pip version 22.3.1

Answer (score 2):

Try changing you python interpreter. Since you are using vs code you can do that with ctlr + shift + p, then type >python: select interpreter
[image] and change it to the one that has a global next to it.[image] If this doesn't work try with all the interpreters. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it turns out making a virtual environment, installing wheel and only then installing cvzone solves this issue.